# como hacer que mi funcion de jquery se ejecute dentro de un modal en una carpeta que se include

Tags: jquery

Buenas sou autoditacta en programacióny java, jquery no domino bien. necesito de ayuda para un problema que me surgido, tengo en mi html varios modals, los puse todos en un carpeta llamada planilha donde cada modal esta como un archivo php.
El problema en si es que todos las jquery de los otros modals funcionan menos los de este archivo:

> modalregistroexcur.php

Dentro de este archivo tengo un modal con este formulario

```
                <form id="form_excurssao" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onclick="formexcurssao();" >
                <input type="hidden" name="idUsuario" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">


                <div class="form-group col-md-12" onclick="ocultar_hospedagem();">
                  <label for="requer_quarto" class="control-label" style="margin-right: 20px;">¿Precisa cadastrar hospedagem para esta excurssão? </label>
                  
                  
                    <label class="radio-inline" >
                      <input type="radio" id="requer_quarto" name="requer_quarto" value="1" checked> SIM
                    </label>
                    
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" id="requer_quarto" name="requer_quarto" value="0"> NÃO
                    </label>
            
                </div>

              <div class="row col-md-12"><!--row md-12-->
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
             
                    <label class="control-label">Nome excurssão</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="escurname" id="escurname" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
                        <span class="field-explanation" style="font-size: 14px;">ex. Cabo frio/RJ-Outubro 2019</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
               
                    <label class="control-label">Valor R$</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="number" name="valor_excur" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Origem</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="origem" id="origem"  class="form-control input-lg" name="email" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
              </div><!--row md-12-->
              <div class="row col-md-12"><!--row md-12-->
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Destino</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="destino" id="destino" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 
                    <label class="control-label">Data ida</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="date" name="data_ida" id="data_ida" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  
                    <label class="control-label">Data volta</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="date" name="data_volta" id="data_volta" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="hospedagem">
             
                    <label class="control-label">Hospedagem</label>
                    <div id="hospedagem">
                        <input type="text" name="nome_hotel" id="nome_hotel" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
                        <span class="field-explanation" style="font-size: 14px;">ex. Pousada recanto verde</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  
                    <label class="control-label">Horario ida</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="time" name="horas_ida" id="horas_ida" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  
                    <label class="control-label">Horario volta</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="time" name="horas_volta" id="horas_volta" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                </div><!--row md-12-->
                
     
     

                  <!--inicio container img-->
                              <div class="container2" onclick="imgexcurssao();">
                                  <div class="row"> <!--rowimg-->   
                                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"> 
                                          <label>Imagens</label> 
                                          <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
                                          <div class="input-group image-preview">

                                              <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
                                              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                  <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                                                      <span class="fas fa-fw fa-times"></span> Apagar
                                                  </button>
                                                  <!-- image-preview-input -->
                                                  <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                                                      <span class="fas fa-fw fa-folder-open"></span>
                                                      <span class="image-preview-input-title">Buscar</span>
                                                      <input type="file"  name="imagempreview" id="imagempreview" accept="image/*" /> <!-- rename it -->
                                                  </div>
                                              </span>
                                          </div><!-- /input-group image-preview [TO HERE]--> 
                                      </div>

                                  </div><!--rowimg--> 
                                   
                              </div><!--fin container img-->
               
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_excurssao" name="btn_excurssao">Registrar</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <span  id="msgexcur"></span>
```

El modal abre normalmente pero no funciona ninguno de los jquerys referente a cada función dentro del archivo:

> scripts.js

```
//<!-- Imagem form-excurssão-->
function imgexcurssao(){

$(document).on('click', '#close-preview', function(){ 
$('.image-preview').popover('hide');
// Hover befor close the preview
$('.image-preview').hover(
    function () {
       $('.image-preview').popover('show');
    }, 
     function () {
       $('.image-preview').popover('hide');
    }
  );    
});

$(function() {
// Create the close button
var closebtn = $('<button/>', {
    type:"button",
    text: 'x',
    id: 'close-preview',
    style: 'font-size: initial;',
});
closebtn.attr("class","close pull-right");
// Set the popover default content
$('.image-preview').popover({
    trigger:'manual',
    html:true,
    title: "<strong>visualização</strong>"+$(closebtn)[0].outerHTML,
    content: "There's no image",
    placement:'bottom'
});
// Clear event
$('.image-preview-clear').click(function(){
    $('.image-preview').attr("data-content","").popover('hide');
    $('.image-preview-filename').val("");
    $('.image-preview-clear').hide();
    $('.image-preview-input input:file').val("");
    $(".image-preview-input-title").text("Buscar"); 
}); 
// Create the preview image
$(".image-preview-input input:file").change(function (){     
    var img = $('<img/>', {
        id: 'dynamic',
        width:250,
        height:200
    });      
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // Set preview image into the popover data-content
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $(".image-preview-input-title").text("Mudar");
        $(".image-preview-clear").show();
        $(".image-preview-filename").val(file.name);            
        img.attr('src', e.target.result);
        $(".image-preview").attr("data-content",$(img)[0].outerHTML).popover("show");
    }        
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });  
});

};



 <!--Mostrar ocultar input-radio-hospedagem-->
function ocultar_hospedagem(){

$("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
    var valor = $(event.target).val();
    if(valor =="1"){
        $("#hospedagem").show( );

      
    } else if (valor == "0") {
        $("#hospedagem").hide(

          function () {
        $('#nome_hotel').removeAttr("required");
        $("#nome_hotel").prop('required',false);
    });
      
    } else { 
        // Otra cosa
    }
});

};
//<!-- Fim Mostrar ocultar input-radio-hospedagem-->

function formexcurssao(){
$("#btn_excurssao").click(function(e) {
    
     
        var datos_form = new FormData($("#form_excurssao")[0]);
        var rota = "insertar_escurcao.php"
        $.ajax({
          url: rota,
          type: "POST",
          data: datos_form,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
         
          
        })
        //$("#form_excurssao")[0].reset();
        .done(function (retorna) {
           
          $("#msgexcur").slideDown('slow').html(retorna);

          //Apresentar a mensagem leve
          retirarMsg();
        })
        .fail(function () {
           alert('error en la conexion al servidor')
        });
         function retirarMsg() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                              
                }, 4000);
                
            };
e.preventDefault();
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

viéndolo por encima, puedo ver que estas llamando un evento dentro una función.

Tienes un HTML con

```
<div class="container2" onclick="imgexcurssao();">
```

Estas esperando que ocurra algo al presionar sobre ese "div", pero tu función de JS.

```
function imgexcurssao(){
```

Lo unico que esta haciendo es activar una serie de eventos como:

```
$(document).on('click', '#close-preview', function(){
```

Entonces si aún no le has dado clic a ese div  "onclick="imgexcurssao()", tus eventos no estarán escuchando, por lo tanto no funcionaran.

1. Remueve la función imgexcurssao del JS e intenta de nuevo.
2. Ya que no tienes experiencia, usa eventos heredados para evitar problemas.

Ejemplo: Cambia

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
```

Por:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(event){
```

Funcionan igual pero la gran diferencia es que el primero solo escuchará los input tipo radio que se cargaron al iniciar la pagina y no luego.
La clase heredada como la segunda lineal del ejemplo, siempre estará dispuesta a escuchar los input tipo radio de lo que ya se cargo en el HTML y lo que se cargue luego.

OJO: Esa clase heredada aplica para todo tipo de evento, ya sea click, change, keyup, keydown, mouseover, mouseleave, dblckick, etc.

Ajústalo y nos cuentas como te fue.